# Is it possible to create a mutable shared data structure without using accumulators in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to spark and there are somethings which are quite unclear to me. But basic knowledge dictates that only accumulators are mutable variables which can be updated across executors and its value can be retrieved by driver. Any other variables initialized in the code , which are updated across executors the updated values are not relayed back to the driver as they are separate JVM's.

I am working on part of a project which stores offsets from zookeeper in a data structure for future use. As the offsets are obtained on executors, it was almost impossible to have a shared data structure which will update offsets per partition back to the driver as well.That is until I came across this code in https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html.

```
AtomicReference<OffsetRange[]> offsetRanges = new AtomicReference<>();
directKafkaStream.transformToPair(rdd -> { 
    OffsetRange[] offsets = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
    offsetRanges.set(offsets);    return rdd;
}).map(
    ...
    ).foreachRDD(rdd -> {    for (OffsetRange o : offsetRanges.get()) {
        System.out.println(
            o.topic() + " " + o.partition() + " " + o.fromOffset() + " " + o.untilOffset()
        );}    
        ...
    });
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(offsetRanges.get()));
```

This contradicts the underlying theory as when I access the value of  `AtomicReference<OffsetRange[]> offsetRanges` in my driver I get the correct updated value(as updated in the `transformToPair` method in the executor code ) even though it should return me a null or empty response. Please can someone explain me this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a mutable shared data structure without using accumulators in spark?

No.

> This contradicts the underlying theory as when I access the value of

It doesn't, because the value is not modified outside driver. The closure of `transformToPair` is executed on the driver, not executors.

Therefore `offsetRanges.set(offsets)` is executed on the same JVM where the original `offsetRanges` value lives.

Comment: That explains it. I was under the opinion everything inside the closures is executed on the executors. Is there a rule of thumb to follow where we can figure out whether a particular function is executed on driver or executor?

Comment: @RonakHingar You should really ask this as a separate question. Whatever deals with an RDD can only be executed on the driver. Whatever RDD method you use is usually (but not always) executed on executors. Easy, isn't it? :)

Comment: @JacekLaskwski That's the most concise explanation I have encountered so far. Thanks!